# Press any key command

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with getting the circle and the text to rotate along my site horizontally. The circle needs to start rolling when you press any key.

Comment: When asking a question, attach all the relevant information related to the question. You mentioned you did most of the CSS so at least post them.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of animation and transitions. Allow me to try. Well anyway you can do it without animation if you `:hover` on it. This is done using the property `transition` and that's it actually. The rest is just a matter of changing properties of the element.

```js
// circle click
document.querySelector(".circle").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector(".rail").classList.toggle("active")
})

// also keypress
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
  document.querySelector(".rail").classList.toggle("active")
})
```

```css
.rail {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 2s all ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*
.rail:hover .circle {
  left: 600px;
  transform: rotate(720deg)
}
*/

.rail.active .circle {
  left: 600px;
  transform: rotate(720deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="rail">
  <div class="circle">
    Click Me
  </div>
</div>

Or Press any key (focus document first)
```

Comment: That's a sweet animation, good work! @techwixtobe, you can modify this easily, add a class like "activated" on key press and use it in the selector instead of ":hover".

Comment: I'll modify my answer @burklay

Comment: @ITgoldman, I guess event listening part should start with `document.body.addEventListener("keydown", ...` since @techwiztobe wants it start with a key press.